# Java Stack Trace: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Seq while trying to run jar having class for Snowflake account connection

Tags: java, scala, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, noclassdeffounderror

I have written Scala class which is showing tables from one of the Snowflake database. I have imported com.snowflake.snowpark._ & com.snowflake.snowpark.functions._ libraries.
When I do sbt compile & sbt run, I am able to see database tables as output.

.jar file gets generated in <>project-folder>\target\scala-2.12

**When I try to run this .jar using scala, I get error as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Seq**
but when I run simple helloworld.jar as "scala helloworld.jar" --> it runs properly & display the output

Here is my class in scala program:

```
class Weather{
  def disp(){
    // Replace the <placeholders> below.
    val configs = Map (
      "URL" -> "https://<*****>.snowflakecomputing.com:443",
      "USER" -> "<*****>",
      "PASSWORD" -> "<******>",
      "ROLE" -> "<*****>",
      "WAREHOUSE" -> "<*****>",
      "DB" -> "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA",
      "SCHEMA" -> "WEATHER"
    )
    val session = Session.builder.configs(configs).create
    session.sql("show tables").show()
    }
}
```

I need to use this jar in Snowflake UDF like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Weather_Tables()
RETURNS NUMBER
LANGUAGE JAVA
IMPORTS = ('@snowpark_stage/snowflake_connection_12jan_2.12-1.0.jar')
HANDLER = 'Weather.disp';
```

my build.sbt file content:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.11"
//scalaVersion := "2.11"
// That is, to create a valid sbt build, all you've got to do is define the
// version of Scala you'd like your project to use.

// ============================================================================

// Lines like the above defining `scalaVersion` are called "settings". Settings
// are key/value pairs. In the case of `scalaVersion`, the key is "scalaVersion"
// and the value is "2.13.3"

// It's possible to define many kinds of settings, such as:

name := "snowflake_connection_12jan"
organization := "ch.epfl.scala"
version := "1.0"

// Note, it's not required for you to define these three settings. These are
// mostly only necessary if you intend to publish your library's binaries on a
// place like Sonatype.


// Want to use a published library in your project?
// You can define other libraries as dependencies in your build like this:

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.2"
resolvers += "OSGeo Release Repository" at "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/"
libraryDependencies += "com.snowflake" % "snowpark" % "0.11.0"
//libraryDependencies += "com.snowflake" % "snowpark" % "0.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"

// unmanagedClasspath/includeFilter := "lib"

// Here, `libraryDependencies` is a set of dependencies, and by using `+=`,
// we're adding the scala-parser-combinators dependency to the set of dependencies
// that sbt will go and fetch when it starts up.
// Now, in any Scala file, you can import classes, objects, etc., from
// scala-parser-combinators with a regular import.


Compile/console/scalacOptions += "-Yrepl-class-based"
Compile/console/scalacOptions += "-Yrepl-outdir"
Compile/console/scalacOptions += "repl_classes"
```

Please guide me if anyone know how to solve this error.

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow! Could you share your build.sbt file content? Most probably you need to also add Scala standard library to your CLASSPATH or package Scala into the target jar by using plugin like sbt-assembly.

Comment: Hi Alexey, I have added my build.sbt file content in the body above.
I am new to sbt as well as scala. Can you please suggest what I need to add in build.sbt file ?

Comment: I am able to run using plugin sbt-assembly

Comment: I am trying to run a java code to read table from Snowflake. Using this https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/java/example.html

I am using snowpark 1.2.0 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.snowflake/snowpark/1.2.0

and getting error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext
at com.snowflake.snowpark_java.SessionBuilder.<init>(SessionBuilder.java:19)
at com.snowflake.snowpark_java.Session.builder(Session.java:52)
at SnowparkExample.main(SnowparkExample.java:18)

Any help would be appreciated